# postgresql - select 4 columns, 1 of the columns requires filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

Beginner PostgreSQL user here, don't have a great grasp of JOIN or CASE yet.

What's the best way to filter in my select statement so that I can get the following output:

- signup_month
- total_signups
- **business_signups**
- total_users

example table:

| date | signup_email | tier | users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-05-02 | personal | trial | 1 |
| 2014-05-04 | personal | subscription | 1 |
| 2014-05-12 | personal | subscription | 2 |
| 2014-05-25 | business | trial | 1 |
| 2014-06-02 | personal | subscription | 1 |
| 2014-06-20 | business | subscription | 10 |
| 2014-06-30 | business | trial | 5 |

Sample output:

| signup_month | total_signups | business_signups | total_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| may | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| june | 3 | 2 | 16 |

Here's a basic query that just outputs 3 columns (signup_month, total_signups and total_users). I'm having trouble adding a 4th column that just counts business_signups from the signup_email column since it requires counting only values that = 'business'

```
SELECT DATE_PART(month,signup_date) AS signup_month,
       COUNT(signup_email) AS total_signups,
       SUM(users) AS total_users

FROM signups
GROUP BY signup_month;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation, which in Postgres uses `filter`.

However, you probably want to include the year with the month, so I recommend `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', signup_date) AS signup_month,
       COUNT(*) AS total_signups,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE signup_email = 'business') as business_signups,
       SUM(users) AS total_users
FROM signups
GROUP BY signup_month
```